# Exported file not move like in the blender animation

Tags: animation, export, animation-nodes, gltf

I created a simple low poly character and I animated using blender.

When I play the animation in blender it looks fine.. no issue...

see image:

[image: blender ok]

but when I exported in glb or glTF format .. something is wrong!

[image: blend 2]

I cant'understand why.. I used the constraints childof to follow the Head movement on the animation since the Hat is a different object.

What I'm doing wrong?

[image: bl]

Comment: I don't think the "Object Constraint" can export to glTF format.  You may need to make the hat part of the skinned mesh.

Comment: Hello. What version are you using? Please upload your test file on a issue on https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO